# Detecting deadlocks WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, deadlock

we have a quite large winforms desktop application. Our application runs every once in a while into a deadlock and we are not sure how this happens.

We do know that this is caused by a locking operation. So we have quite a lot code parts like this:

```
lock (_someObj)
  DoThreadSaveOperation();
```

Our approach to be able to detect what the deadlock was caused by we want to convert all those lock operations into something like this:

```
bool lockTaken = false;   
var temp = _someObj;
try {   
    System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(temp, 1000, ref lockTaken);
    if (!lockTaken)
    {
      // log "can't get lock, maybe deadlock, print stacktrace
    }
    DoThreadSaveOperation();
}   
finally {   
   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(temp);   
}
```

This "lock service" should be at a central position. The problem is that it then has to be called like this:

```
  LockService.RunWithLock(object objToLock, Action methodToRun);
```

That would mean that we had to create a delegate function for each statement which is executed after a lock.

Since this would be a lot of refactoring, I thought I'd give a try on stackoverflow if you guys have a better/good idea about this and also ask for your opinion.

Thanks for you help =)

Comment: there are some possible option here : http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/617472-overload-lock-command-maybe-others

Comment: Consider Using ReaderWriterLockSlim. Most of the times you have operations that are allowed to occur in parallel (for examples read) and you have excluse operations. This would increase performacne and also minimize locks

Comment: Deadlock is a pretty serious bug in your code.  The code you wrote doesn't fix the bug, it tries to ignore it and runs code without taking the lock.  You added a bug.  A really nasty one.

Comment: @HansPassant my goal is not to ignore it. I will certanly raise an exception and will shutdown the application. I just want to get clue how the deadlock is created in the first place, since we can't reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the existing `lock` functionality closely models a `using` statement, I suggest that you wrap up your logic in a class that implements IDisposable.

The class's constructor would attempt to get the lock, and if it failed to get the lock you could either throw an exception or log it. The Dispose() method would release the lock.

You would use it in a `using` statement so it will be robust in the face of exceptions.

So something like this:

```
public sealed class Locker: IDisposable
{
    readonly object _lockObject;
    readonly bool _wasLockAcquired;

    public Locker(object lockObject, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        _lockObject = lockObject;
        Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject, timeout, ref _wasLockAcquired);

        // Throw if lock wasn't acquired?
    }

    public bool WasLockAquired
    {
        get
        {
            return _wasLockAcquired;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_wasLockAcquired)
            Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
using (var locker = new Locker(someObj, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
{
    if (locker.WasLockAquired)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Which I think will help to minimise your code changes.